# Hypothesis test of sample mean of non identical Gaussians

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, t-test, sample

It is well known that given iid gaussians $Y_i \sim \mathcal{N}(m, v^2)$, with unknown mean and variance, then $t = \frac{\hat{m}-m}{\hat{v}/\sqrt{n}}$ follows a student-t distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom. We can use this statistic for a hypothesis test for the mean under the null hypothesis.

Now if we instead let $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2)$, such that the sample mean is given by

$\hat{\mu}:=\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum \mu_i, \frac{1}{n^2}\sum \sigma_i^2\right) := \mathcal{N}\left(\mu, \sigma^2\right)$,

then what is the distribution of the test statistic used for testing $\mu$ under the null hypothesis? Alternatively, how can I perform a hypothesis test for $\mathcal{H}_0:\mu<0$ vs $\mathcal{H}_1:\mu\geq0$?

Comment: In the second model you need to define $\mu$. Are you assuming $\mu=\mu_i$ and all $\mu_i$ equal under the null hypothesis? Do you assume you know the $\sigma_i^2$? If you don't, it's hard, because you only have a single observation for every $\sigma_i^2$, meaning that you can't estimate them without making further assumptions about them.

Comment: @ChristianHennig: thx for ur comment. Added a clarification on what $\mu$ is, i.e. mean of means, which is what we want to test. The problem comes from someone incorrectly assuming the samples are iid and performing a hypothesis test, when samples are in fact from different unknown Gaussians, i.e. how bad is this incorrect assumption. But I believe we still need more information since we have n samples for 2n unknowns?

Comment: Without knowing anything more about the $\sigma_i$ and $\mu_i$ we can't even know how bad it is. There are many possibilities.

Comment: @ChristianHennig: for the source data, it is reasonable to assume that $\mu_i/\sigma_i=\text{constant}$ for all $i$. Does this lead us anywhere?

Comment: @ChristianHennig: Othwerwise I believe one can instead assume $\mu_i\equiv\mu$.  Might not help due to estimating vol...

Comment: If you assume $\mu_i/\sigma_i=c$ *and* all $\mu_i$ equal, this means that all $\sigma_i$ are the same as well and the problem is gone. With less restrictive assumptions, chances are something can be done, but I suspect that would require some development work that I'm not willing to do just for replying on CV. Also in my opinion it would require more detailed knowledge of the real situation, in order to see what kind of assumption can be justified that is just enough to allow identification of the parameters.

Comment: Another thought is that it's generally not the job of probability models to be true. If I assume something as i.i.d. ${\cal N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, this does *not* mean that it really has to be true, but rather that it's an appropriate representation of the random variation in the situation. If your $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i$ vary unsystematically, it may still be appropriate, or a non-normal i.i.d. model with mean $\mu$ that can be applied without estimating all the $\sigma_i$. Also this depends on knowledge about the situation, e.g., it will *not* work if the $\sigma_i$ are systematically increasing.